# Appending the conditions in rails including joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are 3 tables which are joined and there can be where conditions which may or may not exists based on the parameters passed like

> A.joins(b: :c).where(a:{id:1}, b:{id:2}, c:{id:4})
>
> A.joins(b: :c).where(a:{id:1})

There can be any combination in the where condition. How can I implement this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write logic to conditionally send further where methods based on your own logic.

```
my_thing = A.joins(b: :c)
my_thing = my_thing.where(a:{id:1}) if ...
my_thing = my_thing.where(b:{id:2}) if ...
my_thing = my_thing.where(c:{id:3}) if ...
```

Comment: Okay that should work but how do I execute the query through the variable?

Comment: Conventionally you would iterate through the result set using #each, or you could convert the result to an array with #to_a. It depends on what you want to do with the data